# Multiple File upload Multer middleware working on local server but on server it goes to pending state / hangs after running once

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, file, multer

I have a problem with multer middleware. I created the middleware and set the static express files to the uploads folder.

Index.js File

```
import emailroutes from './routes/emailroutes.js'

app.use(express.json({ limit: '25mb' }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false, limit: '25mb' }));
app.use('/uploads', express.static(path.join('uploads')));
app.use('/email', emailroutes);
```

Then in the routes file, using multer as middleware

```
import EmailController from '../controller/EmailController.js'
import { storageMultiple } from '../helpers/storage.js'
router.post('/', protect, storageMultiple, EmailController.postEmail)
```

Multer middle ware function is as follows.

```
import multer from 'multer';
import md5 from 'md5';
var filepatharray = [];

const diskStorageMultiple = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'uploads');
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        while (i < req.files.length) {
            filepath = md5(Date.now() + i)
            const mimeType = file.mimetype.split('/');
            var fileType = mimeType[1];
            if (fileType == 'vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet') {
                fileType = 'xlsx'
            } else if (fileType == 'text/plain') {
                fileType = 'txt'
            } else if (fileType == 'text/csv') {
                fileType = 'csv'
            } else if (fileType == 'vnd.ms-excel') {
                fileType = 'xls'
            } else if (fileType == 'vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document') {
                fileType = 'docx'
            } else if (fileType == 'msword') {
                fileType = 'doc'
            } else if (fileType == 'vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation') {
                fileType = 'pptx'
            } else if (fileType == 'vnd.ms-powerpoint') {
                fileType = 'ppt'
            }
            const fileName = filepath + '.' + fileType;
            filepatharray.push({
                path: filepath + '.' + fileType,
                name: file.originalname
            })

            cb(null, fileName);
            i++;
        }
    },
});
const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, true)
};


const storageMultiple = multer({
    storage: diskStorageMultiple,
    fileFilter: fileFilter).array(
    'files'
);

export { storageMultiple , filepatharray}
```

When i change this to single file upload, it workds fine, Following is the code for multer for single file.

```
const diskStorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, './uploads');
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        filepath = md5(Date.now() + req.user.id)
        const mimeType = file.mimetype.split('/');
        var fileType = mimeType[1];
        if (fileType == 'vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet') {
            fileType = 'xlsx'
        } else if (fileType == 'text/plain') {
            fileType = 'txt'
        } else if (fileType == 'text/csv') {
            fileType = 'csv'
        } else if (fileType == 'vnd.ms-excel') {
            fileType = 'xls'
        } else if (fileType == 'vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document') {
            fileType = 'docx'
        } else if (fileType == 'msword') {
            fileType = 'doc'
        } else if (fileType == 'vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation') {
            fileType = 'pptx'
        } else if (fileType == 'vnd.ms-powerpoint') {
            fileType = 'ppt'
        }
        const fileName = filepath + '.' + fileType;
        filepath = filepath + '.' + fileType
        cb(null, fileName);
    },
});
const storage = multer({ storage: diskStorage, fileFilter: fileFilter }).single(
    'file'
);
```

When i am using multiple files, then i am sending as "files" in multer and when single file, then it is "file"

I am expecting that if someone helps to debug where is the issue on server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`req.files` is available after the processing, so there is no point of reading `req.files` with `while` loop in `filename` function, which means you need to remove multiple storage handler completely, and use only single, and determine single and multiple file uploads per route. Try this:

```
const storage = multer({ storage: diskStorage, fileFilter: fileFilter })

// single
router.post('/', protect, storage.single('file'), EmailController.postEmail)

// multiple
router.post('/', protect, storage.array('files'), EmailController.postEmailWithMultipleFiles)
```

And if you need `filepatharray`, you can extract that from `req.files`

The difference is that with multiple files, files are stored in `req.files`, and with single in `req.file`, so in your case you might not need single at all..

Comment: Alright, I got it. Its working, req.files is what i need in controllers.